# Converting to and from Base64 in Powershell 5.1

Tags: powershell, base64, powershell-5.1

I've found a couple of resources (including [Convert base64 string to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334928/convert-base64-string-to-file), which is practically a duplicate here since it's one of the resources I used to build this) but I can't seem to get it working.

I've got the following code (roughly - obviously it's stripped down,) and I can verify most of the steps of the process as per the comments.

```
$pic = Get-Content 'testpic.png'
# $pic looks like a binary dump.

$picBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($pic)
$ $picBytes is an array of bytes. Quite spammy.

$picEncoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String($picBytes)
# $picEncoded is indeed a Base64 string. Halfway there!

$picDecoded = [Convert]::FromBase64String($picEncoded)
# Also an array of bytes. I'm assuming they're right for now...

$outFile = "pic.png"
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($outFile,$picDecoded)
# but I get no output file and no error?
```

What am I missing here? For what it's worth, I'm willing to look at other solutions - but the Base64 is somewhat important (since I'm storing the data in the script.)

Comment: What is the value of `$outFile`?

Comment: $outFile = "pic.png"

Sorry, didn't separate that out from the other lines.

Comment: Check for pic.png in c:\windows\system32. And use a full path!

Comment: Nothing in system32, but... why. Just why. Yes, providing a full path appears to work (although my conversion is messed up, but that's a different rabbit hole.)

Comment: Forgot to say thanks @G42 - sorry, it's incredibly frustrating that I banged my head against this for 3 hours straight, only to find that the solution was a pattern that's unlike anything else in my script.

Comment: You might find it directly under C:\... cant remember where else .net methods default to. Either way glad to hear it's sorted.

Answer (score 5):

**To read a *binary* file as-is into memory in PowerShell, use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-AsByteStream` switch** (in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)) / **`-Encoding Byte`** (in *Windows PowerShell*, i.e. versions up to v5.1), and **add the `-Raw` switch for efficiency** when you're reading *all* bytes into memory *at once*:

```bash
# In PowerShell (Core) v7+
# Note: In Windows PowerShell, you must use 
#       -Encoding Byte instead of -AsByteStream
$picBytes = Get-Content testpic.png -Raw -AsByteStream
```

<sup>Note: This change in syntax between the PowerShell editions is unfortunate, as discussed in [GitHub issue #7986](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7986). If enough people show interest, it is *conceivable* that `-Encoding Byte` will be reintroduced for cross-edition consistency and compatibility.</sup>

`$picBytes`, as a `[byte[]]` array, can then be passed *directly* to [`[Convert]::ToBase64String()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Convert.ToBase64String)

---

**To pass a *file name/path* to a .NET method, *always pass a full path***, never a relative path or mere file name:

This is necessary, because **.NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's**.
This discrepancy is unfortunate, but cannot be avoided, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375).

In the ***simplest* case** - if your current location is a *file-system* location that is *not* based on a *PowerShell-specific* drive:

```bash
$outFile = "$PWD/pic.png" # Use *full path*
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($outFile, $picDecoded)
```

The **fully robust** approach requires more work:

```bash
$outFile = Join-Path (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath pic.png
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($outFile, $picDecoded)
```